# Looking for cells on table that aren't empty

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table called `DueInTable` with a field called `RepairNumber`.

How do I write an SQL statement that just returns records in a gridDataView where this field is not empty?

This is what I have tried putting into the `OnLoad` event of the Form:

```cs
label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
string data = "Select * from DueInTable WHERE RepairNumber = !NULL";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand(data, connection));
adapter.Fill(ds);
DataView DV = new DataView();
DV.Table = ds.Tables[0];
Repair_dtGrdVw.DataSource = DV;
```

Comment: The syntax is `IS NOT NULL`, in all databases. You can't compare anything to NULL, even if you used the correct comparison operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking for NULL (or not NULL values), you should use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

So your query should be:

```
Select * from DueInTable WHERE RepairNumber IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks ill give it a go when I get home.

Answer (score 5):

`WHERE RepairNumber = !NULL` actually means in SQL *where repairNumber is not something 'undefined'*. Since 'something undefined' (or from which you can't determine the value) can never be 'something undefined', comparing with `=` will always fail.

That is why there is an `is (not) null` operator:

```
WHERE RepairNumber is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from DueInTable WHERE RepairNumber IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string data = "Select * from DueInTable WHERE RepairNumber IS NOT NULL";
```